# How to get dynamic suiteXmlFile name from pom.xml in java file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

My pom.xml reads as :-

```
<property>
                            <name>haltonfailure</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>delegateCommandSystemProperties</name>
                            <value>true</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <reportsDirectory>test-output\${buildTag}</reportsDirectory>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${inputXML}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

And all the dynamic parameters have been passed using Jenkins. But how can I read the dynamic inputXML name in my testbase class so that I can apply some conditions on the basis of this xml file? As whenever I tried to read this file, I always get ${inputXML} but I need the value which I have passed from Jenkins.

Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's been long time so, I'm no sure you are still looking for the solution.
But...

You will need to create a Suite xml dynamically before running your test.

1. Create a java program(It doesn't really need to be java though) to generate suite xml file.
2. Run Maven with parameters

Your java program would be like this.

```
    String suiteName = System.getProperty("suiteName", ""); // <-- get argument value from your VM
    
    XmlSuite suite1 = new XmlSuite();
    suite1.setName(suiteName);

    // XmlTest
    XmlTest test1 = new XmlTest(suite1);
    test1.setName("TmpTest1");

    Map<String, String> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameterMap.put("datasheetPathListPath", "This is the parameter");
    test1.setParameters(parameterMap);

    List<XmlClass> classes1 = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    XmlClass xmlClass1 = new XmlClass("your.package.ClassName");
    classes1.add(0, xmlClass1);
    test1.setXmlClasses(classes1);

    String fileContent = suite1.toXml();

    FileWriter fileWriter;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter("filepath/generated_testNg_file.xml");
        fileWriter.write(fileContent);
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(suite1.toXml());
}
```

Then send values with mvn like this

```
mvn
clean
compile
test-compile
exec:java
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false
-Dexec.classpathScope="test"
-Dexec.mainClass="package.YourJavaClassNameThatGeneratsSuiteXmlFile"
-DsuiteName=YourSuiteName
test
```

If your java program is not under test (/src/test/) remove the line for -Dexec.classpathScope

The mvn command will compile your code before running your program. Your program will create a suite XML file. Then it will run tests with the suite XML file.